# Are there any two real nonzero numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $a^2+ab+b^2 = 0$ Why or why not?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, quadratics

Are there any two real nonzero numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $a^2+ab+b^2 = 0$ Why or why not?

$$a^2+ab+b^2=(a+b)^2-ab=0$$ iff $$(a+b)^2=ab \tag{1}$$
but $(a+b)^2 = a^2+2ab+b^2 $ so equation 1 couldn't possibly be true.

Also, when $a=b\ne 0$, $(a^2+ab+b^2)(a-b) = a^3-b^3 =0$.

Comment: Huh? Sounds like you just argued in a circle. Here's a major **HINT**: Complete the square in the original quadratic.

Comment: I guess you're correct. Divide the entire equation by $b^2$ and it'll reduce down to a quadratic equation.

Comment: Your first equation is wrong. You should remove the $2$ on the left-hand.

Comment: What happens if (i) $a=b\ne0$, (ii) $a\ne b$ & you multiply by $a-b$?

Comment: @J.G. When $a=b\ne 0$, $(a^2+ab+b^2)(a-b) = a^3-b^3 =0$

Comment: @Edmund Can distinct reals have the same cube?

Comment: @J.G.  No distinct reals cannot have ths same cube so $a=b$ and must both must be zero for the equation to true. I think I understand the reasoning now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint :**

$$a^2 + ab + b^2 = \left( a + \frac{b}{2}\right)^2 + \frac{3b^2}{4}$$

Comment: After completing the square and taking the square root I find $a = b(\frac{-1\pm i\sqrt{3}}{2})$. Therefore you cannot find two non-zero reals such that $a^2 + ab + b^2 = 0$.

Comment: @Edmund No need to use the square root : the expression is the sum of two non-negative terms, so both terms are zero, so $b=0$ and then $a=0$.

Answer (score 4):

Fix $b\neq0$ and try to solve in $a$. This a second order equations so the possible values of $a$ in terms of $b$ are

$$ a_{1,2}=\frac{-b\mp \sqrt{-3b^2}}{2}$$

So, for any non zero real value $b$ the possible values of $a$ are complex conjugated because $-3b^2<0$. Therefore you cannot find two non-zero reals such that $(a+b)^2=ab$.

Comment: Your discriminant is differrent to what I've learned thus far i.e. $b^2-4ac$. "Second Order equations"? Have you used differentiation to find the solution. I've only studied quadratics.

Comment: @Edmund The coefficient $b$ is actually $b$ and $c=b^2$

  $\sqrt{b^2-4(1)(b^2})=\sqrt{-3b^2}$

Answer (score 0):

One way is to start from $$a^2+ab+b^2=b^2\left(\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^2+\frac{a}{b}+1\right)=0$$ so letting $x=\frac{a}{b}$ we get the quadratic equation $x^2+x+1=0$ which has no real roots. This is similar to the idea hinted at in the comment by RiverX15.

Answer (score 0):

$$a^2 + ab + b^2 = \left( a + \frac{b}{2}\right)^2 + \frac{3b^2}{4}=0$$
Since the two terms are non-negative, thus
$$\left( a + \frac{b}{2}\right)^2= \frac{3b^2}{4}=0$$
Therefore
$$a=0,\quad b=0$$